# Jacobson radical of a noncommutative ring

Tags: ring-theory

If R is a commutative rings I know that J(R), the Jacobson radical of $R$, coincides to all $r \in R$ such that the elements $$1+s_1rs_2\in U(R)$$ are units of $R$ for any $s_1,s_2  \in R$.

My question is if this result is also true in the noncommutative case. If not, is it possible to construct a counterexample?

In the noncommutative case $J(R)$ is defined as the intersection of all left maximal ideals and also coincides to the intersection of all right maximal ideals.

For example, in J. Lambeck's book " Lectures on Rings and Modules" it is written in Proposition 3 from Section 3.2 that the Jacobson radical is the set of all elements $r \in R$ such that $$1-rs$$ is a right invertible for any $s \in R$.

Since $R$ is not commutative I guess we cannot deduce that $1-rs$  is a unit. Moreover I think that the left analog of this statement is this 
$J(R)$ consists of the set of all $r \in R$ with the property $1-sr$ is left invertible for any $s \in R$.

Thus one cannot draw the conclusion that $1-rs$ (or $1-sr$) is a unit in $R$, i.e it is both left and right invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true (but not immediately obvious from the definition). You can find a proof, for example, [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/05/30/the-jacobson-radical/).